# .Binding checkbox error in windows vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, data-binding, binding, bindingsource

In vb.net visual studio 2013 windows forms, I noticed when using in binding checkbox checked (slow and sometimes error at run time)     while using "checkstate" works correctly.

Is there way to bind checkbox with checked and unchecked only without null without problems?

Image:

[image]

Sample code:

```
Sub bindingTest(container As Control, sql As String, BindingSource1 As BindingSource, BindingNavigator1 As BindingNavigator)
    Dim field As String

    Dim str As String = ""
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, CSql.sqlDatabaseConnString)
    ds = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BindingSource1
    For Each oc As Control In container.Controls
        If (TypeOf (oc) Is CheckBox) Then
            Dim oType As CheckBox
            oType = CType(oc, CheckBox)
            field = oType.Tag.ToString
            oc.DataBindings.Clear()
            If varcheckState = True Then
                '' working fine 
                oType.DataBindings.Add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("checkstate", BindingSource1, field, True))
            Else
                ''' slow and sometimes not working 
                oType.DataBindings.Add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", BindingSource1, field, False))
            End If
        End If


    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unconnected to your issue, may I recommend three improvements to your code? Firstly, if you're just going to use one `DataTable` in a `DataSet` then don't use a `DataSet`. Just create a `DataTable`. Secondly, you can do away with that `If` statement if you write your `For Each` loop as `For Each oType In container.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()`. Thirdly, there's no need to use a `Binding` constructor because the `Add` method will accept the same arguments.

Comment: As for the issue, what is the data type of the columns you're binding and are they nullable?

Comment: data types are bit and yes they nullable

Comment: If they are nullable then why do you want to bind `Checked` rather than `CheckState`? Do you not want to be able to distinguish `NULL` form `False`?

Comment: I want null to be displayed as unchecked or false